# Confusing quote from an article

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is an excerpt from a CNBC article.

What does "only some students have to worry about what that means for their chances" mean? Who are "some students?" Are they legacy students or non-legacy students?

> Top schools now have record low admission rates, but only some students have to worry about what that means for their chances. Legacy admissions, at elite institutions especially, put a select few at a distinct advantage.
>
> Harvard's incoming class of 2021 is made up of over 29 percent legacy students, reports The Harvard Crimson. Last year's applicants who had Harvard in their blood were three times more likely to get into the school than those without. (cnbc.com, 9/6/2017)

Comment: It is not explicit -- you're supposed to work it out for yourself.

Comment: wow that fact is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

The article is saying that if your parents went to Harvard, the admissions office takes that as a plus, meaning you are more likely to get accepted.

Therefore, in:

> *only some students have to worry about what that means for their chances*

"some students" is referring to students who don't have a Harvard blood line. They will worry more because they don't have the extra advantage in these times of record-low admissions rates.

Comment: @J.R. - It sounds like you don't have any "pull" (only "push") . . . ;)

Comment: Non-legacy students account for about 70% of  the incoming class of 2021. Can this propotion of students be called "some students?"

Comment: @JasonB - Unless I happen to provide the fifth and binding vote ... :-)

Comment: @Fuji - Yes, "some students" can account for pretty much any subset of a larger group. The word "some" needn't imply a majority (as does _most_) or a minority (as would _few_).